# Is there a way to pass extra information on a Selenium Grid request?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I'm trying to see if there is a way to pass extra information to the hub from a given request.

The capabilities has the ability to ignore parameters which aren't used, but I wondering if there was a way they could be echoed to the grid UI console?

Key examples could be logon user, IP / Machine name it was sent from etc.

Is this possible?

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: When you say extra information, in what context are you talking about? From where do you intend to pass this info to the hub ? It would be good if you could please help add more information.

Comment: Basically when I do a request I want to see information - after restarting the hub I noticed I got the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems after restarting the hub, I can now see abc-whoami and abc-executingfrom parameters i've added in. Just add this to the list of desiredcapabilities and ensure your availability matcher (if custom) ignores these values.

Comment: Just to add an update to this - the new webdriver specification disallows this method of passing parameters unfortunately :(